# Some members of package not visible - Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyephem

I have a relative simple problem with Pycharm. It seems to ignore some members of packages such as Pygame or PyEphem. For instance, when I type ephem + dot, Pycharm shows me just a few classes and functions avaliable for this package, ignoring many classes such as Uranus (I can make an assignment x = ephem.Uranus() without any errors, but Pycharm doesnt show me any avaliable methods for x). I use standard syntax:

```
import ephem
```

I always work on fresh virtualenv. I have checked interpreter paths. PyEphem is obviously installed for my environment. What may cause the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PyEphem does not list objects like Uranus literally in the text of its `__init__.py` file, but instead loads them dynamically by scanning a table inside of the C library "libastro" that PyEphem is a mere wrapper around. Since it cannot see the name `Uranus` anywhere in the text of the Python module, PyCharm does not know that it will be there at runtime.

If you open an Issue on GitHub, I will get this fixed in the next version by pivoting away from the table-driven code and toward a literal list of planets!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will post an issue on GitHub then :)

Answer (score 0):

Does PyEphem show up when you go to Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter?

If you make a Run Configuration to execute that module from the PyCharm runner (making sure the run configuration points to the project's Python interpreter), does it give an import error?